# Find all functions $f: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ satisfying $f(xf(y) + f(x+y)) = y(f(x)+1)+f(x)$

Tags: functions, functional-equations

Can you tell me if my solution is so far correct and help me complete the second case?

**The statement of the problem :**

Find all functions $f: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ with the following property:
$$
f(xf(y) + f(x+y)) = y(f(x)+1) + f(x) , \forall x,y \in \mathbb R.
$$

**My approach** :

For $x = y = 0$ we get
$$
f(f(0)) = f(0).
$$
For $x = 0$ we get

$$
f(f(y))=y(f(0)+1)+f(0) , \forall y \in \mathbb R.
$$

Now the function $y \mapsto ay+c$ is bijective , where $a$ and $c$ real constants and $a \neq 0$ . So , for $f(0) \neq -1$ we get
$$
\begin{align}
&y \mapsto y(f(0)+1)+f(0) \text{ is bijective,}\\ 
\implies &y \mapsto f(f(y)) \text{ is bijective,}\\ 
\implies &f \text{ is injective and $f$ is surjective,}\\
\implies &f \text{ is bijective}.
\end{align}
$$
Making $y = 0$ in the main equation we get
$$f(f(x))=f(x) ,\forall x \in \mathbb R. 
$$
And since $f$ is bijective we obtain that
$$f(x)=x ,\forall x \in \mathbb R,
$$
which satisfies the initial equation.

Now we have left the case where $y \mapsto y(f(0)+1)+f(0)$ is not bijective , more precisely when
$$
\begin{align}
f(0) &= -1 \\
\implies f(f(y)) &= f(0) = -1 ,\forall y \in \mathbb R. 
\end{align}
$$
Making $y=0$ we get
$$f(-x+f(x))=f(x),\forall x \in \mathbb R. 
$$
From here I didn't know what to do. I think that we either have to show that $f \equiv -1$ or reach a contradiction. I hope that at least the first part is correct.

I am open to all your suggestions and solutions. Thank you!

Comment: In the first case of the proof, setting $y=0$ directly only gives $f(xf(0)+f(x))=f(x)$ but by using that $f$ is bijective, we have that $xf(0)+f(x)=x, \forall x \in \mathbb{R}$. In particular $x=0$ allows us to see that $f(0)=0$ and recover $f(x)=x$ as you said. I wanted to point this out just in case you forgot about the first term in the argument on the left hand side.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note that $f(x) \equiv -1$ is also a solution of the functional equation

$$ f(xf(y) + f(x+y)) = y(f(x)+1) + f(x) , \qquad \forall x,y \in \mathbb{R} \tag{1}\label{fe}$$

To examine other possibilities, assume that $f$ is not identically $-1$.

1. Let $a \in \mathbb{R}$ be an arbitrary element satsifying $f(a) \neq -1$. Then plugging $x = a$ to $\eqref{fe}$ gives
   $$ f(af(y) + f(a+y)) = y(f(a) + 1) + f(a). $$
   This shows that $f$ is surjective.
2. Now we plug $x = 0$ to $\eqref{fe}$. Then
   $$ f(f(y)) = y(f(0) + 1) + f(0). $$
   Since $y \mapsto f(f(y))$ is surjective, the same is true for the right-hand side. In particular, $f(0) \neq -1$ and this in fact shows that $f$ is bijective.
3. Finally, we plug $y = 0$ to $\eqref{fe}$. Then
   $$ f(xf(0) + f(x)) = f(x), $$
   hence by the injectivity of $f$ we get
   $$ x f(0) + f(x) = x, \qquad\text{i.e.,}\qquad f(x) = (1 - f(0)) x. $$
   This then shows that $f(0) = 0$ and therefore $f(x) = x$.

---

**Conclusion.** The functional equation $\eqref{fe}$ has two solutions: $f(x) \equiv -1$ or $f(x) = x$.

Comment: Thank you so much ! Is my part with f(0)=0 correct ?

Comment: @LastX, I am not sure how you concluded $f(0)=0$.

Comment: Using the fact that it is bijective , so f(f(0))=f(0) results in f(0)=0

Comment: @LastX, Note that you used the (unproven equality) $f(0)=0$ to obtain $f(f(x))=f(x)$. Without knowing $f(0)=0$ in advance, you can only conclude $f(xf(0)+f(x))=f(x)$. (Of course, the last identity is enough to conclude $f(0)=0$ as in my answer.)

Comment: for x = y = 0 we get f(f(0)) = 0 , putting x = 0 (())=((0)+1)+(0), assuming f(0) != -1 we get that f is bijective and coming back to f(f(0))=f(o) we get that f(0)=0

Comment: @LastX, I see your point now. I guess I was confusing myself because, without the assumption $f(0)\neq -1$ I was only able to show the surjectivity of $f$. In your case, by assuming $f(0)\neq-1$, $f$ is also injective and the equality $f(f(0))=f(0)$ is enough to conclude $f(0)=0$. Perhaps you may spell out a few words to let others know how you obtained $f(0)=0$, maybe right after you have derived bijectivity of $f$.